# Json parsing error

Tags: php, html, json, api

I keep getting this error when I parse the trip advisor feed. Trying to pull up the username.

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Here's my code with the link to the feed.

```
<?php
function getCode($url)
{
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
$html=getCode("http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/1.0/location/258705/reviews");
$json = json_decode($html);
$cnt=0;
foreach ($json as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $row)
    {
        echo "Image Url:".$row->text."<br>";
        echo "ID:".$row->id."<br>";
        //username
        foreach($row->user as $row1)
        {
            echo $row1."<br>";

        }


    }
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

?>

Comment: As long as you express a stdClass in string context (e.g. `echo`), you will get this error as string context needs strings to output (that can be object, but only those which implement `_toString()` which is not the case for `stdClass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r($row1);
stdClass Object ( [id] => [name] => Mahwah )
```

Try changing

```
$row1."<br>";
```

to

```
$row1->name."<br>";
```

Comment: Not working for me. I get this error message now "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Look - you can't echo an object. Get familiar with the structure of the data you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the assoc attribute to true on the json_decode function.

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode($html,true);
```

Read more about json_decode [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

---

Also as a suggestion for your next stack overflow post, don't share API keys or other sensitive information.

Comment: There is no need to set that in this case.

Comment: Just realised that now, my point about him not sharing a partner only api key still stands though. haha

Comment: jup, should better just provide exemplary json instead of the key :) - https://eval.in/156628

Comment: @hakre Well atleast I got a free trip advisor key out of this xD (jk jk)

Comment: It's a test key anyway :p